# Aggregations on Realtime Streaming data

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, apache-storm

Can someone explain how does aggregations are performed on real time streaming data using big data technologies like storm, spark, etc.. 
It's non meaningful to calculate on steaming data,  as data keeps on flowing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of streaming frameworks support 'window' which collects tuples (events) in a window and presents it to be aggregated. Tumbling window and sliding window are widely supported, and the units of window are count (tuples) and time.

You can refer below links to get an idea of concepts for window:

https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-101
https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-102

You can calculate aggregation on tuples for latest N mins(may be seconds, hours, or so) via windowing. You may feel the operation as batching, and yes you could also do it via pushing tuples to external storage and do some aggregations with batch frameworks.

In normal, aggregation in batch frameworks will work more efficiently (the aggregation operation is batch oriented), but aggregation on streaming framework on the fly doesn't require external storage (if the window fits in memory) and also doesn't require additional batch frameworks to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In streaming, data is going to stream continuously.So first, we need to accumulate data. For that we use `window`. We first group the data by window where we specify time column and time. Spark will accumulate data for given time and then we will apply aggregation on grouped data.
For example

```
import spark.implicits._

val words = ... // streaming DataFrame of schema { timestamp: Timestamp, word: String }

// Group the data by window and word and compute the count of each group
val windowedCounts = words.groupBy(
  window($"timestamp", "10 seconds"),
  $"word"
).count()
```

For complete understanding of streaming aggregation [refer](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-window.html)